Modelo entidad relación
Cuando estoy trabajando con una relación 1:1 o una relación 1:M y necesito añadir atributos a la relación, ¿esa relación cambiaría a N:M? 
¿Cambia sólo a N:M cuando el atributo que agrego es una fecha?
Añado un ejemplo. TEngo personas que tienen DNI. Relación 1:1. Pero quiero saber y tener controladas todas las fechas de renovación, o llevar un control de cuantas veces se ha renovado el DNI. ¿Qué pasa una vez agrego la fecha?, ¿cambia la cardinalidad? ¿Sólo pasa con atributos tipo fecha o pasa cuando añado otros atributos exclusivos de la relación?

Dices ¿Cambia sólo a N:M cuando el atributo que agrego es una fecha? Agregar un atributo no cambia la relación. Luego dices ...quiero...tener controladas todas las fechas de renovación Tu modelo no soporta todas las fechas soporta UNA fecha, para que soporte muchas fechas debes cambiar el modelo, específicamente la relación 1:1 a N:M. Dicho de otro modo, la relación ha cambiado por un cambio en la lógica de negocios que impacta al modelo, no por agregar un atributo

Si tu hubieras querido guardar solo la última fecha de renovación (se actualiza cada vez que se renueva), puedes agregar ese atributo del tipo fecha y la relación sigue siendo 1:1. El querer agregar TODAS las fechas (un historial) es un cambio en la relación (que hace cambiar el modelo). Por otro lado, puedes guardar la sucursal (ID_SUCURSAL) de donde se renovó en cada ocasión, y el efecto es el mismo, estas cambiando la relación N:M y en este caso no es del tipo fecha

Cierto. Si sólo quiero una fecha, puedo colocar dicha fecha de renovación en la entidad DNI. Pero como quiero guardar todas las fechas de renovación, ese atributo va en la relación, ¿Correcto?. Por lo tanto, como comentas la relación ya no es 1:1, pasa a ser N:M. La relación recibiría también las claves principales de cada entidad. Y las tres juntas serían la clave principal de la relación, para poder almacenar todas las fechas. ¿Voy bien?.

Entiendo entonces, que serían dos modelos diferentes. Como dices. En uno hay un relación 1:1 porque sólo almaceno 1 fecha en la entidad dni, Y en el otro, como quiero almacenar varias fechas, es una relación n:m y pongo el atributo fecha de renovación en la relación. A esto me refiero cuando al ponerle un atributo a una relación 1:1 que almacena varias fechas, la relación cambia a una relación n:M. ¿Puedes confirmarme que mis conclusiones son correctas? No es añadir un atributo lo que modifica la relación, sino los valores que almacena dicho atributo.
